# RelativeLayout - CenterInParent and marginTop

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I has the following XML:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/cover_box"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/cover"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/download" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/mark_download"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:layout_marginTop="90px" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But it's look's like the marginTop is being ignored.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use center in parent the view is put directly in the center. The margin top will only come into play if an object is within 90px of the top of your view. Thus pushing the centered view down to keep at least 90px of space on top of it. So it isn't being ignored but it is not having the effect that you think it should have.

Comment: If that was the case, then changing the margin to a high value would change the position of the image. But I am testing on Android 4.2 and it seems like centerInParent completely overrides any margin in Relative layout.

Answer (score 28):

If you want the 2nd image to be 90dp under the center of the screen, you could replace it with a FrameLayout where you can control the padding to move your image downwards.

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:paddingTop="90dp">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/download" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:src="@drawable/mark_download"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you. Center the framelayout and add padding/

Answer (score 3):

I want the progressbar to shown under `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` so i have added a dummy `TextView` and set it to centerInParent .Then i put my progressbar under it. Now you can increase its distance from center in two ways . First by increasing marginTop in TextView and second increasing TextView height.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/widget"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/splash_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <com.s3.tdd.interfaces.CircularProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/circularprogressbar2"
        style="@style/Widget.ProgressBar.Holo.CircularProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="110dip"
        android:layout_height="110dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put your imageview inside of other ViewGroup (LinearLayout of RelativeLayout layout), leaving the margin of imageview, and doing `android:centerInParent="true"` for the ViewGroup:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:centerInParent="true">
           <ImageView android:id="@+id/download" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/mark_download" android:layout_marginTop="90px" />    
    </LinearLayout>    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a dummy view and center it to parent. Now align your view relative to dummy view using layout:alignComponent and give the marginTop. Now in the code move it according to the width of your view to center it.