# RelativeLayout and vertical margin(margin top ,margin bottom) dose not work for me why?

Tags: android, android-view, android-relativelayout

In RelativeLayout  if   layout_centerVertical or layout_centerInParent are true vertical margin (margin top ,margin bottom) does not work for me why?

```
<RelativeLayout>`
` 
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="900dp"
        android:background="#36648b"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_star_black_24dp"
        />

 </RelativeLayout>`
```

[image]

Comment: what you want to do?

Comment: @Zeeshan Shabbir i just try it

Answer (score 0):

When you `layout_centerInParent="true"` your ImageView, it's being put exactly in center of parent view.

`layout_marginTop="[##]dp"` will affect your layout if an object is within 90px of the top of your view. Thus pushing the centered view down to keep at least 90px of space on top of it. So it isn't being ignored but it is not having the effect that you think it should have.

> source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7895380/5244435